# Tap gesture in UITavleViewCell label recognized, but does not select cell as well

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a `UILabel` which segues to a new view controller. When the tap gesture occurs, the segue works, but always passes data from the only first cell, regardless of which cell the tapGesture is performed in. However, when I first select a cell outside of the label tapGestureRecognizer, and then perform the tap gesture, the data passes successfully b/c I first selected the respective cell.

How can I set the tapGesture to also recognize the cell selection?

P.S. I set up the gesture and segue in storyboard, not code. Also, my data passing code is my prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Why are you using a UITapGestureRecognier? Why don't you just let the UITableView do its work and handle the selection and pushing to detail view?

Comment: I have two labels in each cell with gesture recognizes that segue to two different view controllers.

Comment: Without knowing exactly how its laid out I can't be sure, but I have a feeling thats a bad idea and very unuser friendly. As for fixing your problem, I'd need to see the code for your tapGesture selector.

Comment: Each table cell is about a full screen in height, so there is plenty of room for more than one tapGestureRecognizer. I have no code for the tapGesture other than instantiation with `@property` and `@synthesize`. I used storyboard to set all of my outlets. Could this be the issue?

Comment: It could be. I've never used drag and drop Gestures. I always create and add them in code.

Comment: How would I embed a gesture in a specific label in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're question is a bit light on details, but let me ask: are you determining in your code which cell was selected when the tap occurs?

ie. In your method that fires when a tap occurs, check which cell the tap occurred in by querying the tableview, and from that you can determine which code you need to pass in your prepareForSegue method.

For example, I use this method below to determine which cell was tapped on, and bring up the keyboard for the textfield of that cell. You can easily adapt this to store away which cell was tapped on, then use it in your prepareForSegue to send the right data.

Hope this is what you are looking for. Can't quite tell from your question though!

```
- (void) tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    // get location of tap
    CGPoint tapLocation = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];

    // Query tableview and get location of cell
    NSIndexPath *idp = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];

    // Now get the actual cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:idp];

    // Get handle on text field
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    // Bring up keyboard for that textfield.
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];


}
```